# How to get the template path of a word 2003 document

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I create a new document based on a template (*.dot), I need to know on which template is the document based on.

Is there a way to find out with VBA which template was used for creating this new document? I need the complete path to the template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName
```

Comment: Thanks, this works almost. ;-) In some cases I dont get the correct template. I get instead the normal.dot allthough I created a document from an other template (CurstomerLetter.dot). Any Idea?

Comment: How are you creating the new doc in the first place?

Comment: Our customer has about 38'000 !! templates. In some cases I get the correct template name. However I create the new template always from the Windows Explorer with a double-click (same effect with right-click and then "New"). If I get the "normal.dot" as template allthough I created a document from an other template, I found out that the value in the property of the template is wrong as well. It's also "normal.dot". I dont know if these templates are corrupt.

Answer (score 4):

You may also use a built-in document property to access the template name: `ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyTemplate)`

I don't remember why theres has been sometimes differences between the two results; you must try it out. please be aware that accessing sometimes the built-in properties sets the document in a dirty state, so that it is useful to save the ActiveDocument.Saved state before and reset it after having accessed the property.

**[UPDATE]**
I've had again a look into the way you're creating the documents. If it's at your customer with 38.000 templates, I guess your problem are "fake" templates. I've just did a test with Office 2003:

1. Create a new document "TestTemplate.doc" with same content and save it as doc file. Close it.
2. Go to Windows Explorer and rename the document to "TestTemplate.dot". This provokes Windows Explorer to treat it as a template, not as a document. The default DDE command for templates is not "OPEN", but "NEW", what you can also see if you do a right-click on the file ("New" is bold, while with documents "Open" is bold).
3. Double-click the fake template: Word creates a copy of the document, so a new file named "Document2" or whatsoever.
4. Go to the VBA Editor, and type ?ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate, and you'll see "Normal" as answer. Type ?activedocument.Type = wdTypeTemplate  and you'll see "False" as answer.

Sp I guess the documents "Without template" are only copies of other documents, and not of templates. So you have no way to find the base template.

Comment: ok, I will try it out tomorrow. I dont have a word on this computer right now. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunatly I get the same result. I get with [ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName] the full path to the file of the Normal.dot and with your suggestion I get just the name "Normal", allthough I created the document with a template for a letter. I mean I can see the letter with all textboxes and text but the reference to the tempalte is wrong.

Comment: You're right. It seems to be there are a some "fake" templates. When I open a "corrupt" template for edit and save it again as ".dot", then it works. Thank you very mutch. Andy

Comment: Don't know if it can help, but I've a similar issue. I found that if the template is not available (network share, private folder, etc.), Word switch to `normal.dot`. However, using `ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyTemplate)` as suggested returns the correct filename of the template.